Revision is gone, likely just rejected, but how could it vanish without any trace?
I have changed

Getting a "Request to run job refused because the job is already running" When no job is running?

to

Why do I get a "Request to run job refused because the job is already running" when no job is running?

at Getting a "Request to run job refused because the job is already running" When no job is running? to make it a full question. I see that this is not the same question anymore since it now asks for the "Why" and not clearly for a fix.
Yet, I wonder is why my revision is not in the history. If it was rolled back, it should be there. And if it was rejected, I should see it under "All actions" in my DBA SE profile.
What has happened here? How could it vanish without any trace? If it was not just this little change, but a lot of work, all of this work would be gone. I would like to avoid that if I can. If it cannot be avoided, I need to save my changes in my own files until they get passed, which cannot be in the sense of the community.

You should see your suggested edit history on your profile's activity tab: https://dba.stackexchange.com/users/current?tab=activity&sort=suggestions

Make sure you have the filter set to All or Suggestions.
It's not obvious, but clicking on the word "Reject" below "suggested" takes you to the detail page:

For more, see the FAQ, How do suggested edits work?

I get it. After years of membership I have misread "revisions" as "suggestions".
